# Multiple non-wildcard certificates on EBS?

Tags: ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've recently inherited management of a relatively small app running on Elastic Beanstalk. I've advised the client that they need SSL, which I've set up and is working ok on their primary domain. However, they themselves have a couple of clients who use their own domain name to log in to this service and now rather predictably they're getting certificate mismatch errors.

Without using a wildcard, is it possible to persuade EBS to support multiple SSL certificates on the same instance?

Comment: I don't know about multiple certs, but is there a reason you aren't considering a single cert with SAN (SubjectAlternativeNames), often called "multi-domain"? That's probably cheaper, and even works for lame old clients without SNI like WindowsXP.

Comment: My client wants to avoid the risk of any other clients' domains being visible in the SSL certificate.